# Cannot convert expression type 'NHibernate.IQueryOver<T,T>' to return type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<T>'

Tags: .net, nhibernate, session, repository, iqueryable

I'm sure I'm doing this wrong, but I've been picking at it for a while. I'm trying to implement an IRepository Find method, and I just can't seem to work out how. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The following code gives me the red squiggly line with the error message posted as the question.

```
   IQueryable<T> IRepository<T>.Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return sessionManager.OpenSession().QueryOver<T>().Where(predicate);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `.Query<T>()` extension method instead.

Comment: *hands his head in shame*.. thanks for that. No more red squiggly s. :)